# Probability of getting at least one number out of 10 with 4 chances

Tags: probability

Let's say that in a lottery, 4 balls are drawn at random from a pot of 10 balls, numbered from 0 to 9. The drawn balls are not put back in the pot. If your ticket matches the 4 drawn balls you win the jackpot. However if the last number on your ticket ends with one of the four drawn balls, you get your money back. My question is if you have 2 tickets and both ending in different numbers, what are the chances that:

I get my money back for exactly one ticket,
I get my money back for at least one of the tickets, 
I get my money back for both of the tickets

Thanks

Comment: Each ticket has a chance of $\frac{2}{5}$ to hit one of the drawn digits.

Comment: Hi Peter, I can't see that. Could you explain it a little further?

Comment: 4 digits are drawn, so the end-digit is one of the 4 drawn digits in 4 out of 10 cases.

Comment: Ok, that's the chances for exactly one then, right? Thanks

Comment: No, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are

$$\frac {10*9}{2} = 45$$

possibilities for the ending digits of the two tickets.

In

$$\frac{4*3}{2} = 6$$

cases, both hit. So, the probability is $\frac{6}{45}=\frac{2}{15}$.

In

$$\frac{6*5}{2} = 15$$

cases, no ticket hits. So the probability is $\frac{15}{45} = \frac{1}{3}$.

So, 24 cases remain for the event : Exact one ticket hits. Probability $\frac{8}{15}$

Comment: But correct me if I'm wrong. In this case you're taking all the possibilities for the ending digits. My question is, given you have a particular one out of them which are the chances. Does this match what you explain? sorry for being stubborn, I'm very rusty..

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Took me a while

Answer (score 3):

For $i=1,2$ let $E_{i}$ be the event that you get your money back
on the $i$-th ticket (i.e. the last number of $i$-th ticket agrees
with one of the $4$ distinct numbers drawn). Then:

$P\left(E_{1}\wedge E_{2}\right)=P\left(E_{2}\mid E_{1}\right)P\left(E_{1}\right)$.

Here $P\left(E_{1}\right)=\dfrac{4}{10}$ and $P\left(E_{2}\mid E_{1}\right)=\dfrac{3}{9}$
(i.e the probability that - under condition that my first the last
number on first ticket belongs to numbers drawn - this is also
the case for the last number on second ticket).

This leads to $P\left(E_{1}\wedge E_{2}\right)=\dfrac{12}{90}=\dfrac{2}{15}$.

Likewise $P\left(E_{1}\wedge E_{2}^{c}\right)=P\left(E_{2}^{c}\mid E_{1}\right)P\left(E_{1}\right)=\dfrac{6}{9}\times\dfrac{4}{10}=\dfrac{4}{15}$.

Consequently the probability of money back exactly once will equal $P\left(E_{1}\wedge E_{2}^{c}\right)+P\left(E_{1}^{c}\wedge E_{2}\right)=\dfrac{8}{15}$.

Finally the probality of no money back at all is: $1-\dfrac{2}{15}-\dfrac{8}{15}=\dfrac{1}{3}$.